# how to read data from variables using header function in php

Tags: php

in the root of my project folder i have a file called index.php and a directory called views which contains a file called page_one.php ...

index.php file has the follwing code:

```
<?php
$action = "one";

if ($action == 'one') {
    $name = "John";
    //include './views/page_one.php';    
    header("Location: views/page_one.php");
}
?>
```

and page_one.php has the following code:

```
<?php echo 'Name = ' . $name; ?>
```

in the above code I have commented out the line with include because that works perfectly..I want to pass the value of $name using the header function..Is there a way of doing it WITHOUT sending the value in the URL?

I want the address in the URL to change when page_one.php is accessed that is why I am using the header function instead of include...

Comment: You can add it to a session, and then grab it on the next page.

Comment: if there is a lot of data then wont adding all the data to the SESSION array be inefficient??

Comment: @falahmahmood How much is a lot?

Comment: Inefficient? Doubt it, at least not for anything you'd be doing. By the time it becomes inefficient you will probably understand PHP much better than you do today. You plan on serving thousands of people per second?

Comment: You just said you wanted to send the $name variable, that doesn't sound like much at all.

Comment: So everyone agrees that I should use SESSION to send the data then...just out of curiousity is there a way of sending the value of $name using header() BUT WITHOUT including the value in the URL??

Comment: Why not use include "views/page_one.php"?

Comment: not using include because I want the URL to reflect the page being visited...

Comment: Technically SESSION does not "send" data to `page_one.php`. SESSION simply opens up a text file on your server, stores some data, and closes the text file. So first `index.php` performs this and once you send the user to `page_one.php` then that script opens the session file and reads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Qirel as per said, try using session. Do something like this in `index.php`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = "John";
    header("Location: views/page_one.php);
    exit();
?>
```

and inside `page_one.php`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
    unset($_SESSION['name']); // remove it now we have used it
?>
```